# Is there a reason why warp doesn't call toWaiApp?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Just for the sake of it, I'm interested in why `warp` doesn't call `toWaiApp` as stated in the comment:

```hs
toWaiApp :: YesodDispatch site => site -> IO W.Application
toWaiApp site = do
    logger <- makeLogger site
    toWaiAppLogger logger site


-- | [...] Automatically calls 'toWaiApp'. [...]
warp :: YesodDispatch site => Int -> site -> IO ()
warp port site = do
    logger <- makeLogger site
    toWaiAppLogger logger site >>= Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.runSettings (...)
```

Why not calling `toWaiApp`:

```hs
-- | [...] Automatically calls 'toWaiApp'. [...]
warp :: YesodDispatch site => Int -> site -> IO ()
warp port site = toWaiApp site >>= Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.runSettings (...)
```

**Update**: I'm on `yesod-core-1.6.14`.

Comment: Does the stuff in `(...)` refer to `logger` by name? That would be one obvious reason to want to have the logger available.

Comment: Is toWaiAppLogger not similar enough to toWaiApp to make the documentation accurate?

Comment: @amalloy Shame on my head, you are right. `logger` occurs in `(...)`.